# how can the UILabel become a CALayer and cause a crash?

Tags: swift, memory-management, ios9

I've got a custom `UIView` of which several instances are created inside a loop:

```
let models = CDMyModel.MR_findAllSortedBy("position", ascending: true) as! [CDMyModel]

for view in myViews {
    view.removeFromSuperview()
}

self.myViews.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

for model in models {
    let myView = MYFaqView(width: CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame))
    myView.titleLabel.text = model.title
    myView.content.text = model.content
    myView.titleLabel.sizeToFit()
    self.scrollView.addSubview(myView)
    self.myViews.append(myView)
}
```

I do sometimes see crashes in Crashlytics in the line with `myView.content.text = model.content`:

[image]

According to the crash I assume it has something to do with memory, but I really don't know how the myView could have been released at that point.

All this happens in `viewWillAppear:`. Could the removing before has to do something with this? But I assume everything happens on the main thread, so this shouldn't be a problem as well - I'm really stuck here.

The crash happens on iOS 9.

**EDIT**

MyFaqView init method:

```
init(width:CGFloat) {
    self.width = width

    super.init(frame: CGRectZero)

    self.addSubview(self.titleLabel)
    self.addSubview(self.toggleImageView)
    self.addSubview(self.separatorView)
    self.content.clipsToBounds = true
    self.addSubview(self.content)

    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

**EDIT**

```
let content:UILabel = {
    let l = UILabel()
    l.numberOfLines = 0
    if let font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 14) {
        l.font = font
    }
    return l
}()
```

Comment: Can you include the source code for `MYFaqView`'s init method?

Comment: show initialization of content view/label?

Comment: Run under Instruments with the Zombies instrument. Does it find a zombie?

Answer (score 2):

These problems are always very tricky to track down.

Basically, what is happening is memory corruption. The address `0x14f822a0` that was previously occupied by your `UILabel` **content** has been used by something else, in this case a `CALayer`. You can verify this if the crash happens locally by entering `po 0x14f822a0` in lldb and sure enough it will output that address to be of type `CALayer`.

With these errors, although the crash line can provide a clue, it is not always the cause of the error. Something has already happened elsewhere.

Although Swift is mostly memory managed, there are still pitfalls for the unwary. Personally I have seen two principal causes of memory corruption. The first is with retain cycles caused by self referencing closures. The second - *more pertinent to your problem* - is with views related to Storyboards and Xibs.

If we follow this through logically, we can consider that the `CALayer` now occupies the address space previously taken by your `UILabel` **content**. The runtime attempts to send a message to the object is thinks occupies that address, and that is caught by a Swift runtime assert which then triggers a  `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` crash.

Now, for some other object to have taken up residence at that address, the original inhabitant the `UILabel` **content** must have been released. So why would the runtime release **content**? Because it is no longer required, i.e. it is not a subview or property of any view that it still required.

I would bet that if you change **content** to be a subclass `UILabel` and add a `deinit` method that you then breakpoint, you will be surprised to see that it is being unexpectedly deinitialised early on. To test this create a type as follows:

```
class DebugLabel: UILabel
{
   func deinit
   {
     NSLog("Breakpoint on this line here!")
   }
}
```

Then change **content**'s type to be the `DebugLabel` above.

So why is all this happening? My money is on you having one of your view properties that has been created programmatically as being either `weak` or `unowned`. Perhaps you had these set up previously using an `IBOutlet` that you then removed but forgot to remove the `weak` designator?

Check through each and every one carefully and I am sure you will find the cause of the problem above. Nothing that is created programatically either by using an initialiser or `UINib` should be designated `weak` or `unowned`.

Answer (score 0):

Brief viewing shows me two potential problems:

1. You can break iterator here, that cause undefined behavior - 
   `removeFromSuperview()` really remove the view from the hierarchy and release it and reduce the number of elements in myViews.

> for view in myViews {
>       view.removeFromSuperview() }

2. What do you do here? Seems you repeat the previous step.

> self.myViews.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

Comment: ```myViews``` is an array of all the views which I need in ```updateViewConstraints```, so the ```removeAll``` doesn't actually remove them from view hierarchy - I think it's no problem then, right?

Comment: Why not to use just scrollView.subviews? Try to remove dependency from myViews and see what will happen

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't crash often, for most users it doesn't - I couldn't reproduce it one single time, but in crashlytics I see multiple crashes at that place, so I don't know if I solved it or not

Comment: What's there inside MYFaqView init?

Comment: What about setting all the subviews in storyboard and make outlets to them?

Comment: @MaratAl Don't ever use `scrollView.subviews`. It contains the scroll view indicators even when the indicators are hidden, and you shouldn't be messing with them.